# ServiceWorker multiple SCSS files for dynamic require in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sass, service-worker, dev-to-production

I have been searching around but can't find an answer to this. I managed to dynamically load the required scss files for the create-react-app dynamically, so as to have a light and dark modes. I use the vanilla framework with React.js, and am doing the following in app.js

```
useEffect(
() => {
  console.log('use effect')
  if (cookies['mode'] === 'light' || cookies['mode'] === 'dark') {
    console.log('cookies_mode: '+cookies['mode'])
    setUiMode(cookies['mode'])
  } else {
    console.log('cookies_mode: light')
    setUiMode('light')
  }

  if (uiMode === 'light') {
    require('./app.scss')
    setNavBgColor('#FFF')
    setNavFgColor('#111')
  } else {
    require('./app-dark.scss')
    setNavBgColor('#080808')
    setNavFgColor('#FFF')
  }
},
[cookies, uiMode]
```

)

and upon reload the correct stylesheet is used. This is working perfectly in the development server (i.e npm start) but when I build it with npm run build and then serve it, all the site works fine, except for the ability to switch modes, so it stays in dark mode always... super strange because the cookies are being set correctly.. Could this be because of having enabled the service worker and it is caching my stylesheet even if it has different name?

Code in my github: https://github.com/averageflow/joes-software

Don't know if it helps but here is the way it switches themes:

```
function toggleUIMode () {
if (uiMode === 'dark') {
  setCookie('mode', 'light', { path: '/' })
  setUiMode('light')
  window.location.reload(false)
} else {
  setCookie('mode', 'dark', { path: '/' })
  setUiMode('dark')
  window.location.reload(false)
}
console.log('set ui mode to')
console.log(uiMode)
```

}

Comment: why don't you use lazy loading?

Comment: how do you do that?

Comment: I think there are better approaches for changing layout theme! You can provide two components(it can be HOC) Dark and Light and then use lazy loading inside. Each style comes whenever the component renders. I think you should reconsider your approach for solving this!

Comment: i am just used to php pages and guess I am spoiled in these aspects, do you have a link to learn more about modern lazy loading in functional components? I don't have a single class in my project, am doing better off with the states and namespaces, thanks

Comment: This seems good => https://blog.logrocket.com/lazy-loading-components-in-react-16-6-6cea535c0b52/